# Elaborate Primers (books) on time-series decomposition and factorization?

Tags: time-series, references, decomposition

I am looking for masters or PHD level books and flagship papers on time-series decomposition including mathematical notations/theorems.
I recently did a biology bachelor's thesis on singular spectrum analysis in sleep EEG and am currently looking for a method for a bachelor's degree in mathematics on the same issue.
I saw recent advances including Tikhonov regularization and am aware of some ARMA-strategies.

As reference I would like to name: Singular Spectrum Analysis of Biomedical Signals. Other technologies are in use: Dynamic principal component analysis, Empirical mode decomposition or Tensor decomposition (sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165027015001016). Sadly I lack knowledge of good or even sufficient introduction into each method and I am not aware if there is. Generally quite often these are least-square-regularizations for ill-posed problems.

My search will include building new or derived theorems specifically tailored to solve the decomposition problem for EEG's, therefor I am open to classic topics as factorization or similar not mentioned for this case by default.

I am highly interested in mathematical papers and books, possibly not including EEG or other use-cases and I am interested in lengthy PHD level introductions.

Although this is a highly opinionated question, I would like to ask for recommendations.

Comment: Maybe you can add some references teaching us who do not know what is *decomposition problem for EEG's*?

Comment: As reference I would like to name: Singular Spectrum Analysis of Biomedical Signals. Other technologies are in use: Dynamic principal component analysis, Empirical mode decomposition or Tensor decomposition (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165027015001016). Sadly I lack knowledge of good or even sufficient introduction into each method and I am not aware if there is. Generally quite often these are least-square-regularizations for ill-posed problems.

Comment: Can you please add this new info as an edit to the post? Not everybody reads comments ...